# How do you call a common controller method from ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, getjson, nancy

I am using the Nancy framework in asp.net-mvc.  From within the various views, I'd like to be able to call methods from a common module via ajax/getJSON rather than having to duplicate end points in each controller module but have been unsuccessful so far.

Suppose my controller module looks like this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Models;
    using Nancy;

    public class CommonModule : NancyModule
    {
        public CommonModule(IAppRepository repo)
        {
            Get("/EndpointName/{someargument}", async (x, ct) =>
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                int someargument;
                if(int.TryParse(x.apptype, out someargument))
                {
                    var data = await repo.SomeModel.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    result = Response.AsJson(data);
                }

                return result;

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Within my js file, I'd have something like:

```
function callMethod()
{
    var someargument = $('#SomeControl').data('somedata');
    var url = window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + '/CommonModule/EndpointName/' + someargument;
    $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
        //process if/as required;
    })
    .done(function (info) {
        //process if/as required;
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        //process if/as required;
    });

}
```

Is this possible?  If so, how is this done?  Am I just constructing the url incorrectly or is it to do with ensuring the correct reference is present in the .cshtml file?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$('#CommonModulebtn').click(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: '/CommonModule/CommonModule',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { IAppRepository : $('#SomeControl').data('somedata').val() },
    success: function (info) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function callMethod() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/CommonModule/CommonModule",
        type: "GET",
        data: $("#IDFORM").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           alert("ok");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call any controller action from any controller view within your application. And your code is fine. You need to make sure that you  construct correct URL.

I am not familiar with NancyFx routing, but I think that You need to remove 'CommonModule' from the URL so it looks like:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + '/EndpointName/' + someargument;
```

If it is a common module, you may want to change the route on the server:

```
public CommonModule(IAppRepository repo)
{
     Get("/common/EndpointName/{someargument}", async (x, ct) => ...
```

and the URL in JavaScript will be

```
var url = window.location.protocol + '/' + window.location.host + '/common/EndpointName/' + someargument;
```